# Generate different thumbnails for videos in Gallery

Tags: video

Device:  Nexus 7
Android: 4.4.2
Gallery app: 1.1.40304

I have a series of videos with a similar first 30 seconds. The thumbnails for all of them look identical. Is there any way of making the Gallery app calculate a different thumbnail for these videos?

Alternatively, is there any way to display the filename along with the thumbnail? I have to go through to the details menu for each to see the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Not a nice solution, but if you have to access those videos regularly for a long time, you could find the thumbnail files and edit them so you could tell the videos apart.

Also you could find another application which displays the title as well, or an animated preview. VLC player and Mobo player function well for me.